# SSL Certificate with any webhost

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, shared-hosting

Is it possible to buy an SSL certificate from verisign or comodo for exapmle, and use it with my shared webhosting in another company? if yes, how?

Comment: This is a question for your web hosting company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shared web hosting company offers dedicated IP and SSL for your web hotel you should be able to use any certificate out there.

Otherwise, no, you cannot just buy a cert and use it on a normal shared hosting product.

Comment: Depends on the hosting company. If they support TLS Server Name Indication on their server, he can use the certificate without dedicated IP address. Most browsers work fine with that, except IEx running on WinXP.

Comment: And since ~40% still use Windows XP, SNI is not an option. Not unless you do not care the slightest about your users.

Comment: I believe in stating the facts, since you never know what his target segment of users is. It might very well be all mobile users or desktop users using Firefox.